# How to acces a void method from another class?

Tags: java, methods, void

how do I call a void method from another class to a new class with main?
I have two classes, but I don't see the error I am making.

```
public class Person {

    private int age;
    private String name;

    public Person(int a, String n) {
        a = age;
        n = name;
    }

    public void printInfo() {
        System.out.println(age + name);
    }
```

//

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person obj1 = new Person(22, "Dan");
        obj1.printInfo();

    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing a `}` at the end of the `printInfo()` method.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Move the main method to a different class and done.
**TestPerson.java**

```
public class TestPerson {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person obj1 = new Person(22, "Dan");
    obj1.printInfo();

}

}
```

You have few mistakes in your code. It should be like as follows :

```
public class Person {
private int age;
private String name;

//Your constructor was wrong
public Person(int a, String n) {
    age = a;
    name = n;
}

public void printInfo() {
    System.out.println(age + name);

}

}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks but I was wondering if I can print out void in another class there you have main? So public static void main(String[]args) are in another class, and I want to print it out?

Comment: I hope this answer is satisfactory. If you are looking for something else, hit me.;)

Comment: Most welcome. Can you do me a favor by marking it as an answer if this is really you wanted!! I would appreciate it.